# Shell script wont execute on jenkins however manually it will

Tags: linux, git, github, jenkins, automation

This appears to be a really weird issue. I am using Jenkins for automating compilation and build creation. I have a shell script which when I execute manually on gitserver, it is fine but the same script through Jenkins displays 
error:

### Error:

/tmp/hudson829990263989049539.sh: 2: build/envsetup.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Content of the shell script(envsetup.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh
function hmm()
{
cat <<EOF
..................
```

Command used for manual as well as with Jenkins:

```
. build/envsetup.sh
```

I tried various methods e.g. changing the path for script execution, chown and then execute, dos2unix etc but nothing appears to work till now.

Any idea on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The issue got resolved when I put

```
#!/bin/bash
```

in the the build steps in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Run your shell script with **sudo** .

sudo .build/eventsetup.sh

Comment: Thanx Mahi, but this didnt work for me. However, I just answered the stuff that worked. Thanks for trying to answer. :)